# How to cleanly leave Windows 2008 Small Business Server Active Directory

Tags: windows-vista, windows-sbs

I recently set up SBS 2008 and joined the Active Directory on my Vista Machine with the plan of having more computers on the network.  That worked fine.

However, plans have changed and I still only have one machine on the network (along with the server), which is a bit pointless and a waste of electricity.  Is there some clean way to just turn off the server and have my original computer, running Vista Ultimate revert back to it's previous condition?  I would imagine there is, I just don't know how to find it or what it involves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just join the machine to a workgroup and then shutdown the SBS server. The only thing that you will have to do is migrate your profile from the one for your domain user, to the one for your local user.